# Debugging suspend problem with pm-trace

Tags: suspend

Have a computer which has long been unable to suspend ( hangs on resume ) and decided to try and investigate. Using the trace functionality to try and identify the problem driver I end up finding the following:

```
[    1.110545] PM:   Magic number: 5:864:888
[    1.110645] memory memory327: hash matches
```

What on earth is this telling me? It's consistent - every single resume results in the same crash and the same has being flagged - do I have dodgy memory?

I've run the memtest86+ which doesn't come up with any problems on this machine - though I can't recall if I allowed it to run for the full 8 cycles. Surely I'd be getting random crashes with dodgy memory - I'm not doing so.

Comment: A good start is to include your version the type of Ubuntu. Server or Desktop?

Comment: Sorry - It doesn't seem hugely relevant since the problem has persisted over multiple versions and fresh installs of ubuntu with the hope that resume would work again.

I'm now on 21.10, but this failure to resume happened on 20.04 and 19.10. I think it last worked back on 18.04, but the machine has had various bits of new hardware and extra RAM since then

Comment: I have radeon graphics which I know is the bane of suspend and resume, I first suspected that as being the problem which is why I started investigating with pm_trace. I'm just really wondering if anyone can let me know what this pm_trace result means - it seems to suggest something quite basic failing in the process.